# Testing Covergence/Divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Trying to determine if the series converges or diverges

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\log(n)\right)^{-\log\log n}
$$

Comment: You had $n = 1$, which I think should be $n = 2$. Correct?

Comment: No, n=1 was correct.

Comment: @user63782: What are your current thoughts on the problem? You should say what you've tried so far, so that people don't already tell you information you know and also can respond at an appropriate level.
Also, if $n = 1$ was correct, the first term isn't even defined, so the series trivially diverges.

Comment: Just double checked. Definitely n = 1. Comparison test was my initial inclination. With the harmonic series seems to be the overall consensus here. I'm not sure about the Cauchy Condensation Test. I can't really to find any good examples of it, and our book doesn't even mention it. I appreciate the help guys.

Comment: Quick update: Textbook had an error in it. Is shown as n=1, and was later changed to n=2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare
$$
  (\log n)^{\log \log n} = \exp((\log \log n)^2) \ll\exp((\sqrt {\log n})^2) =\exp(\log n) = n
$$
so you series is larger than the harmonic series, which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition here is that $\log n$ grows very slowly, and $\log\log n$ grows glacially slowly. So our terms should approach $0$ too slowly for the sum to converge.

It seems reasonable to try for a proof via a comparison  with the divergent $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. Which of $\frac{1}{n}$ and $(\log n)^{-\log\log n}$ goes more slowly to $0$?

Instead of comparing the functions directly, we compare their logarithms. The logarithm of $\frac{1}{n}$ is $-\log n$. The logarithm of $(\log n)^{-\log\log n}$ is $-(\log\log n)^2$.

It is not hard to show that in the long run, $\log n$ is (much) larger than $(\log\log n)^2$, in the sense that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log\log n)^2}{\log n}=0.$$
For details, we could let $\log n=x$, and examine the behaviour of $\frac{(\log x)^2}{x}$ as $x\to\infty$.

In particular, if $n$ is large enough, then $(\log \log n)^2\lt \log n$. This implies that for $n$ large enough, we have $(\log n)^{-\log\log n}\gt \frac{1}{n}$.

Thus by Comparison our series diverges.